# Solving $y^\prime=xy-y-e^{-x}y^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $y^\prime=xy-y-e^{-x}y^3$

So first I simplified this to $y^\prime=y(x-1)-e^{-x}y^3$

Then used the substitution $z=y^{-2}$, $z^\prime=-2y^{-3}y^\prime$ to get:

$z^\prime=-2z(x-1)+2e^{-x}$

The problem I'm having now is solving this linear differential equation:

$z^\prime+z2(x-1)=2e^{-x}$

I tried the integrating factor $e^{\int 2(x-1)dx}$:

$e^{\int 2(x-1)dx}(z^\prime\cdot2z(x-1))=e^{\int 2(x-1)dx}2e^{-x}$

To get:
$e^{\int 2(x-1)dx}\cdot z+C_1=\int\frac{2e^{\int 2(x-1)dx}}{e^x}=\int 2e^{x^2-2x}dx$

But I'm not sure how to solve the right hand side integral

Comment: You are using correct approach to solve Bernoulli ODE. The integral does not have elementary solution, look up Gauss error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It is $$2\int e^{x^2-2x}dx=-i/2\sqrt {\pi}{{\rm e}^{-1}}{\rm erf} \left(ix-i\right)+C$$
the so called error function